# How can I use $emit to delay a function executing for the next 60 seconds?

Tags: angularjs

In one area of my code in a servicce I have something like this:

```
 $rootScope.$emit('rootScope:success-response')
```

In another area of code I have a function that executes every 60 seconds:

```
 this.$interval(function () {    
    myFunc()
        }, 60 * 1000);
```

How could I stop myFunc from running if there has been an emit of 'rootScope:success-response' in the last 60 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to cancel `$interval`, and set it again, but more efficient solution would be keep timestamp of last emitted event and compare it to current `+Date()` inside `myFunc` - if timestamp is < 60s, just terminate `myFunc` - `return;`.

EDIT:

```
$rootScope.$on('rootScope:success-response', function (){
    YourService.lastEmitted = +new Date(); // fast conversion Date to int
});

--- YourService:

lastEmitted = 1234567;
function myFunc(){ 
    if (lastEmitted < +new Date()){
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you give me an example of how I could compare the timestamp to date?

Comment: Example added - assuming myFunc is in some external Service.